# How to pass the information from a jList in a from to another jList in another frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlist

I have to do a project in which I'm making an application for a Hospital. I have screens (jFrames) for Patients and Doctors, in which I can enter the information of a patient through jFields (or doctor) and the patient will be added to a jList with the identifier (int) and name of the patient. When I click each patient, each field will have the information I previously set for the patient. 
The thing's that I need to make a screen (jFrame) for the Appointments, in which I have a list of the patients I previously entered in the Patient's frame and, when I click, I will be able to see the information of the appointment. ¿How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/300257

Comment: Did you try anything at all? If so, please show us a piece of code.